# How can I make the map be infinite in GMap.NET?

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I am writing a WinForms app using GMap.NET Windows Forms. I noticed that the map is finite. It does not show anything to the east of Australia, for example:

[image]

Notice the white bit on the right.

This is my code to create the map (not including the markers):

```
// gmap is a field generated by the WinForms designer
gmap.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
gmap.MinZoom = 1;
gmap.MaxZoom = 5;
gmap.Position = new PointLatLng(0, 0); // initial position is (0, 0), I moved it to the east

gmap.ShowCenter = false;
```

I want the map to behave similar to Google Maps - if I keep moving east, I will move past Australia and see South America again.

I looked around on the Internet for "gmap.net infinite" and similar keywords. All I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257550/gmap-net-does-not-show-full-map-in-the-control), which is about the map being shown on only part of the `GMapControl`. On the other hand, I want the map to continue infinitely. Maybe I was not using the correct terminology for this.

How can I make the map continue infinitely?

I have also thought of limiting the area that the user can see so that the user never sees the white bits, but all I could find was this unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387972/how-to-limit-the-area-location-i-want-to-view-in-gmap-net-wpf-using-c).

Comment: Maybe it depends on the provider? Did you try with the OpenStreetMapProvider?

Comment: I tried both OpenStreetMapProvider and BingMapProvider. Both shows the same thing. I am starting to think that this is not supported in GMaps.NET @rene

Comment: Judging from implementation of i.e. [Mercator projection](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/799f3a38a65350ff00c21acf9b88c96848bb3880/GMap.NET.Core/GMap.NET.Projections/MercatorProjection.cs#L52) and [PureProjection.Clip](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/799f3a38a65350ff00c21acf9b88c96848bb3880/GMap.NET.Core/GMap.NET/PureProjection.cs#L414) this framework is meant to clip the maps to bounds rather than wrap them around, sorry :/

Comment: @orhtej2 So are there other NuGet packages that I can use to display an infinite map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in discussion section. They said that this feature does not implemented yet

https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/issues/29